# How to count new lines in Internet Explorer?

Tags: javascript, css, internet-explorer

Hey, all.  I'm doing my own syntax highlighter for Javascript and CSS, and I've run into an issue with Internet Explorer (big surprise).  I grab all the contents of a `code.block` tag (example below) using `innerHTML`, and `.split("\n")` that result to get each line by itself.  This works wonderfully except in IE.

I have tried using `innerText` and `.split("\r\n")` also without success.  Can anyone recommend a solution?  If it makes a difference, my `code.block` tags are styled to be `white-space:pre-wrap`.

```
<code class="block css">div#randomBarsDemo {
    width:175px;
    height:200px;
}

div#randomBarsDemo div {
    background-color:#111;
    width:100%;
}</code>
```

Comment: what doesn't work about it? can you provide some example js in your post to demonstrate it not working?

Comment: Sorry!  When I add content back into a `code.block` tag, almost all of the \n characters are missing.

Comment: i'm having trouble following what you're doing. where is the snippet above coming from? is someone typing that into a textbox just as it appears here? and then you're trying to write it out in nicely formatted html?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best thing I've found so far (in IE8 for Windows at least) is to get the **innerText** from a target element, replace `\r` with `<br/>`, and stick this back into the **innerHTML**

```
var el = document.getElementById('target');
el.innerHTML = el.innerText.replace(/\r/,"<br/>");
```

Then, if you want to get the target line-by-line in the future you can `.split()` on `<BR>`.  It *has* to be `<BR>` and not `<br/>` thanks to Internet Explorer's auto HTML parsing.

So to directly answer the question, to count lines, you need to get the `innerText`, and look for `\r`s, not `\n`.  Please let me know if this does or doesn't solve your problem, so I know whether this is helping people or leading them astray.

Answer (score 1):

According to my research, you're going to have more issues with browser consistency other than this problem.  My advice would be to use the script referenced below to fix all of the issues with other browsers as well.

http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/cross-browser-split